# modal-lg from bootstrap cut in a half

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/veLHB.png)

when inspected, modal-lg has the following css

```
@media (min-width: 992px)
.modal-lg, .modal-xl {
    max-width: 800px;
}
```

which when removed, the size of the modal becomes full, but the displayed modal is not as large as when using modal-lg and the results are messy

sorry can't share the code for some reason

hope someone can solve this problem

I want to make the modal to full on one screen, so it doesn't get cut off

Comment: Sorry, can't share answer for some reason.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You need to give us enough information to help. Also tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: Sorry, I've never asked before. Apologize me because the question that I asked was not straightforward, once again I apologize 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you put the bootstrap class 'modal-lg' in the appropriate div (?)